# Import CSV in postgresql without duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql, csv

My query duplicates rows when I import CSV file in to table:

```
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| fullname | formattedvalue | recordTime          |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| text1    | 170.01346      | 09/02/2020 21:45:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| text2    | 24.153432536   | 09/02/2020 21:45:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| text3    | 3.583432424    | 09/02/2020 21:45:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| text1    | 170.01346      | 08/02/2020 21:45:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| text2    | 24.153432536   | 08/02/2020 21:45:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| text3    | 3.583432424    | 08/02/2020 21:45:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
```

And the Query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x
(
"fullname" varchar,
"formattedvalue" double precision,
"recordtime" timestamp
);

COPY tmp_x FROM PROGRAM 'more +1 "D:\MEAS_20200308x.csv"' (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',');

--UPDATE tmp_x
--SET    formattedvalue = ROUND( CAST(formattedvalue as numeric), 3 );

insert into meas_kanal select * from (
select x.*
from tmp_x x
left outer join meas_kanal t on t.fullname = x. fullname AND t. recordtime = x. recordtime
where t. fullname is null AND  t. recordtime is null
) as missing;


DROP TABLE tmp_x;
```

My logic is to check for duplicates on cloumn combination: `fullname` + `recordtime`

When I start the query again, it is inserting the same rows again.

Any idea where I am wrong?

EDIT 2:

I tried and this with the same problem:

```
INSERT INTO meas_kanal
SELECT x.*
FROM tmp_x x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN meas_kanal t ON (t. fullname = x. fullname AND t. recordtime = x. recordtime)
WHERE t.fullname IS NULL AND t. recordtime IS NULL;
```

EDIT 3:
One more fail.

```
INSERT INTO meas_kanal
SELECT *
FROM tmp_x
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM meas_kanal 
                 WHERE (tmp_x.fullname=meas_kanal.fullname and
                       tmp_x.recordtime=meas_kanal.recordtime)
                 );
```

I think that the problem is somewhere else.

Edit 4: Possible solution

BTW I forgot to mention. I don't have a primary key.
Now I make two:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x
(
"fullname" varchar,
"formattedvalue" double precision,
"recordtime" timestamp,
UNIQUE (fullname, recordtime)
);
```

And this insert:

```
insert into meas_kanal(fullname, formattedvalue,recordtime) 
    SELECT fullname, formattedvalue,recordtime FROM tmp_x x
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

For now it's working like I expect. I will write this solution as an answer if no one gives a better solution.

Comment: You should use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @SILENT can you give an example, please?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @SILENT no it don't. Still making double records.

Comment: Is the table in your question how you raw table looks before any query? Can you tell me what columns are found in tmp_x? I'm assuming there is an id column, correct?

Comment: No, the temp table is the same like the other one.

Comment: I re-examined your table and noticed each row is unique. Can you provide a sample of what results you are expecting?

Comment: I make it  unique in my `Edit 4` and when use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is the only solution atm.

Comment: If your first table in your question is how your original data looks, each row has unique combination of columns (I originally thought `recordtime` column had the same value for all rows). For the first table, what results are you expecting your query to result with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209519/discussion-between-hristian-yordanov-and-silent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make two primary keys:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x
(
"fullname" varchar,
"formattedvalue" double precision,
"recordtime" timestamp,
UNIQUE (fullname, recordtime)
);
```

And this insert:

```
insert into meas_kanal(fullname, formattedvalue,recordtime) 
    SELECT fullname, formattedvalue,recordtime FROM tmp_x x
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

For now it's working like I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`

Assuming your current query results with the table you displayed

```
INSERT INTO meas_kanal
SELECT DISTINCT x.fullname, x.formattedvalue, x.recordtime
FROM tmp_x x
```

---

Update 1

Based on your recent comments, if you want the latest recordtime to be inserted, then use `GROUP BY`

```
INSERT INTO meas_kanal
SELECT x.fullname, x.formattedvalue, MAX(x.recordtime) recordtime
FROM tmp_x x
GROUP BY x.fullname, x.formattedvalue
```